# Highcharts: significant decimals in the tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts, decimal

I am trying to change the number of significant decimals. By default is 7, so I am having many 0.0000000s for values smaller than 0.0000001.

I tried `plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter` and `plotOptions.line.dataLabels.formatter`, but they didn't work.

Then, I tried `plotOptions.line.tooltip.formatter` but this only accepts HTML, and I'd like to set something like

```
function() {
    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,10);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run example with 20 decimal, see example http://jsfiddle.net/qPUZw/

```
 tooltip:{
            formatter:function(){
            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,20,',')
            }
        },
```

Seems to working fine.